# probability question, P(A|B) The conditional probability that the unit has at most three rooms, given that it has at least two rooms

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

I'm having issues with the following problem,

**Here is my dataset.**

```
Rooms No._of_units
_____ ____________
1     363
2     2427
3     12474
4     27346
5     31245
6     28606
7     15080
8+    21588
```

**Here is the question**
The conditional probability that the unit has at most three rooms, given that it has at least two rooms, is: __

**Here is what I've tried**

```
sample = {
    1:  363,
    2:  2427,
    3:  12474,
    4:  27346,
    5:  31245,
    6:  28606,
    7:  15080,
    8:  21588
}

n = sum(sample.values())

P_1 = sample[1]/n
P_2 = sample[2]/n
P_3 = sample[3]/n
P_4 = sample[4]/n
P_5 = sample[5]/n
P_6 = sample[6]/n
P_7 = sample[7]/n
P_8 = sample[8]/n

# Probability B is P(1) + P(2) + P(3)
P_B = P_1 + P_2 + P_3

# Probability A is 1 - P(1)
P_A = 1 - P_1

# P(B & A) / P(A)
print(f"{P_B / P_A: .3f}")
```

The solution I get which is wrong is $0.110$ 'rounded to 3 decimals.

I don't need a solution in python. I'm just using it because I don't know R very well.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: OK, so you know the unit has at least 2 rooms ... how many units are there total that have at least 2 rooms?  And *out of those*, how many have at most 3 rooms, i.e. either exactly 2 or exactly 3 rooms? ... in other words, you should not include the units with exactly 1 room. You divide P(B) (which includes P_1) by P(A), but you should divide P(A&B) = P_2+P_3 by P(A)

Comment: Thank you, @Bram28; if you can submit this as a solution, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you know the unit has at least 2 rooms ... how many units are there total that have at least 2 rooms? And out of those, how many have at most 3 rooms, i.e. either exactly 2 or exactly 3 rooms?

... in other words, you should not include the units with exactly 1 room.

So there is your mistake: You divide $P(B)$ (which includes $P_1$) by $P(A)$, but you should divide $P(A\&B) = P_2+P_3$ by $P(A)$

Comment: Thank you @Bram28

Comment: @MichaelWalker You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

Let N be the total rooms in the unit. Because of the condition that the unit has at least two rooms, the sample space is reduced to $N-363$,
and favorable cases in the reduced sample space are $2427+12474$ for $2,3$ rooms

Proceed